# How many lines are executed after IF?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider a part of a SQL script like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tableName', 'U') IS NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tableName]
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_tableName
DROP TABLE dbo.tableName
```

If `tableName` exists, are all three lines executed? What about the rest of my script further down (not included - it creates the table); Is there a way to limit how many lines get executed after the `IF` statement? I can't find an answer on this as it's quite an ambiguous search.

Comment: Use `begin...end`

Comment: You should not count rows, you should count **statements**. The Transact-SQL **statement** that follows an IF keyword and its condition is executed if the condition is satisfied. If you want more staements to be executed, use BEGIN..END as suggested above

Comment: Only the `ALTER TABLE` is included here. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL "IF", "BEGIN", "END", "END IF"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404029/sql-if-begin-end-end-if)

Comment: @Mr JF check the first answer, it has the explanation that you need.

Comment: Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it like below :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tableName', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tableName]
        DROP CONSTRAINT PK_tableName;
        DROP TABLE dbo.tableName;
    END
```

If you don't use `BEGIN` and `END` block, only the first sql statement would be treated under the `IF` condition and the last sql statements would execute every time you run it and you will get error if `tableName` does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Only first query is executed. For more than 1 you need `BEGIN` - `END` block.